# Out of Index Error while Scraping Web Pages and storing information in a list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am currently in a data science Bootcamp and I am ahead of the curriculum for the moment, so I wanted to take the chance to apply some of the skills that I have learned in service of my first project. I am scraping movie information from Box Office Mojo and would like to eventually compile all of this information into a pandas dataframe. So far I have a pagination function that collects all of the links for the individual films:

```
def pagination_func(req_url):
    soup = bs(req_url.content, 'lxml')
    
    table = soup.find('table')
    links = [a['href'] for a in table.find_all('a', href=True)]
    pagination_list = []

    substring = '/release'
    for link in links:
        if substring in link:
            pagination_list.append(link)
            
    return pagination_list
```

I have sort of lazily implemented a hardwired URL to pass through this function to retrieve the requested data:

```
years = ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019']
link_list_by_year = []
for count, year in tqdm(enumerate(years)):
    pagination_url = 'https://www.boxofficemojo.com/year/{}/?grossesOption=calendarGrosses'.format(year)
    pagination = requests.get(pagination_url)
    link_list_by_year.append(pagination_func(pagination))
```

This will give me incomplete URLs that I then convert into complete URLs with this `for` loop:

```
complete_links = []

for link in link_list_by_year:
    for url in link:
        complete_links.append('https://www.boxofficemojo.com{}'.format(url))
```

I have then used the `lxml` library to retrieve the elements from the page that I wanted with this function:

```
def scrape_page(req_page):
    tree = html.fromstring(req_page.content)
    
    title.append(tree.xpath('//*[@id="a-page"]/main/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/h1/text()')[0])
    
    domestic.append(tree.xpath(
        '//*[@id="a-page"]/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/span[2]/span/text()')[0].replace('$','').replace(',',''))
    
    international.append(tree.xpath(
        '//*[@id="a-page"]/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span[2]/a/span/text()')[0].replace('$','').replace(',',''))
    
    worldwide.append(tree.xpath(
        '//*[@id="a-page"]/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/span[2]/a/span/text()')[0].replace('$','').replace(',',''))
    
    opening.append(tree.xpath(
        '//*[@id="a-page"]/main/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/span[2]/span/text()')[0].replace('$','').replace(',',''))
    
    opening_theatres.append(tree.xpath(
        '/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/span[2]/text()')[0].replace('\n', '').split()[0])
    
    MPAA.append(tree.xpath('//*[@id="a-page"]/main/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[4]/span[2]/text()')[0])
    
    run_time.append(tree.xpath('//*[@id="a-page"]/main/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[5]/span[2]/text()')[0])
    
    genres.append(tree.xpath('//*[@id="a-page"]/main/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[6]/span[2]/text()')[0].replace('\n','').split())
    
    run_time.append(tree.xpath('//*[@id="a-page"]/main/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[5]/span[2]/text()')[0])
```

I go on to initialize these lists which I am going to spare posting for sake of text walls, they're all just standard `var = []`.

Finally, I have a `for` loop that will iterate over my list of completed links:

```
for link in tqdm(complete_links[:200]):
    movie = requests.get(link)
    scrape_page(movie)
```

So it is all pretty basic and not very optimized, but it has helped me understand a lot of things about the basic nature of Python. Unfortunately, when I run the loop to scrape the pages after it scrapes for about a minute it throws an `IndexError: list index out of range` and gives the following debug traceback (or one of a similar nature concerning an operation within the `scrape_page` function):

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-381-739b3dc267d8> in <module>
      4 for link in tqdm(test_links[:200]):
      5     movie = requests.get(link)
----> 6     scrape_page(movie)
      7 
      8 

<ipython-input-378-7c13bea848f6> in scrape_page(req_page)
     14 
     15     opening.append(tree.xpath(
---> 16         '//*[@id="a-page"]/main/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/span[2]/span/text()')[0].replace('$','').replace(',',''))
     17 
     18     opening_theatres.append(tree.xpath(

IndexError: list index out of range
```

What I think is going wrong is that the particular page that it is hanging up on either lacks that particular element, it's tagged differently, or there is some sort of oddity. I have searched for a way to error handle this, but I couldn't find one that was relevant to what I was looking for. I honestly have been banging my head against this for the better part of 2 hours and have done everything (in my limited knowledge) but searched every page by hand for some sort of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `xpath()` returned anything before trying to append the result to the list.

```
    openings = tree.xpath('//*[@id="a-page"]/main/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/span[2]/span/text()')
    if openings:
        opening.append(openings[0].replace('$','').replace(',',''))
```

Since you should probably do this for all the lists, you may want to extract the pattern into a function:

```
def append_xpath(tree, list, path):
    matches = tree.xpath(path)
    if matches:
        list.append(matches[0].replace('$','').replace(',',''))
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
append_xpath(tree, openings, '//*[@id="a-page"]/main/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/span[2]/span/text()')
append_xpath(tree, domestic, '//*[@id="a-page"]/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/span[2]/span/text()')
...
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked but it also showed a bevy of issues that I have to work through fixing now. Thank you!